# psql select row from table or default value

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with setting id-value pairs.
I need to select the value of a certain setting id, and if that setting id is not present in the table, I wish to select a default value.
This value is used in a query to delete rows from another table.
Here's the sort of functionality I'm looking for:

```
DELETE
FROM sub_objects
USING object_settings
WHERE sub_objects.object_id = object_settings.object_id
AND (object_settings.setting_type_id = 2 AND object_settings.setting_value = 'B')
OR (there is no setting_type_id = 2 for this object, and the default value = 'B');
```

Note: tables sub_objects and object_settings contain rows related to multiple objects, so some of these objects may have the relevant setting value, and others may require to use the default value.

So how to implement the part in the parentheses?

Comment: Sounds like you want an inner join on the default provider table, a left outer join on the specific values and a coalesce to pick the specific value if it exists and otherwise the default. I'll try to be more specific if you provide a usable example of the schema + sample data as a http://sqlfiddle.com/ then comment here to notify me once it's done.

Comment: See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/19aef/1

Comment: The code is useful, but you haven't explained which table is which, or how it relates to the question.

Comment: @giladrv what should be your output, just show your sample output

Comment: TRY SOMETHING LIKE this `with cte as(
select object_id from object_settings where (object_settings.setting_type_id = 2 AND object_settings.setting_value = 'B') or (object_settings.setting_type_id <> 2 and object_settings.setting_value = 'B')
)
delete from sub_objects so where so.object_id in (select object_id from cte)`

Comment: My desired output would be that sub objects of objects with setting id 2 defined and value equal B, or setting id 2 id not defined and the default equal B, that these sub objects will be deleted. In the provided example, sub objects with ID 1, 3, and 4 will be deleted.